# WP Custom plugin: Create table and insert data once.

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress

This is my complete Wordpress plugin file:

```
<?php
function wp_create_table_install()
{
    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'createtable';
    $sql = 'CREATE TABLE '.$table_name.'(
        id INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name VARCHAR(75)
    );';

    require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($sql);
}

function wp_create_table_insert_data()
{
    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'createtable';
    $id = 1;
    $name = 'WP Create Table!';

    $wpdb->insert($table_name, array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name));
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'wp_create_table_install');
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'wp_create_table_insert_data');
?>
```

When I activate the plugin, it always tries to create a table and insert data. How could I do it once, just in the first plugin activation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A quicker way would be to add  [IF NOT EXISTS] in your CREATE statement so that you don't get an error if your table already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Before running `CREATE TABLE`, you could query `information_schema.tables` to check to see whether or not the table already exists.

Comment: Ok, that solves the problem, and what about the insert query? Thanks.

Comment: Well, obviously, if you don't want an insert if the table already exists, then you just don't do it after the check Demian wrote about.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no way to run something on "install" - surprisingly, WordPress doesn't provide any hooks for install as opposed to activation!

The way people cope with this is to set and test an option - if the option is not set, then create the tables, and if it is set do nothing or do a DB upgrade.   Options are read in and cached so there is no performance penalty to doing this.

```
$opt = get_option(MYPLUGIN_OPTIONS);

$opt['dbversion'] = 100;
...
update_option(MYPLUGIN_OPTIONS, $opt);
```